# Angular v4: Search by name with observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-forms

I'm using Angular v4 and I want to add the ability to search by name, so I have created an service that allow to get list of movies:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Movies }         from '../models/movies';
import { environment }    from '../../../environments/environment';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  searchMovie(query: string): Observable<Movies> {
    return this.http.get(environment.api.baseUrl + environment.api.searchMovie.uri + "?query=" + query)
                    .map((res:Response) => res.json() as Movies)  // Process the success response object
                    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().errors || 'Server error'));  // Process the error response object
  }

}
```

This service is very simple, because send search terms to server and return a Observable.
After this is my html, I'm using reactive form:

```
<section class="search-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form class="form-search" [formGroup]="searchForm" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> </span>
            <input type="text" id="key" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="Search for a movie..." formControlName="key">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Now this is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit }      from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

import { Movies }        from '../../models/movies';
import { Movie }         from '../../models/movie';
import { SearchService } from '../../services/search.service';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  private searchForm: FormGroup;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
  private errorMessage: string;
  private matchedMovies: Array<Movie> = [];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private searchService: SearchService) {
    this.createForm();    
  }

  createForm(): void {
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      key: ['']
    });

    // Check the changes
    this.searchForm.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search query is same as previous
        .switchMap(query => this.searchService.searchMovie(query.key))
        .subscribe(
          (result) => {
            console.log(result);
          },
          error =>  {
            this.errorMessage = <any>error;
            console.log(this.errorMessage);
          },
          () =>  {
            console.log("onCompleted");
          });
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

When I search a movie, it works very well but when the user send a empty string I obtain 422 error from server (it's correct) but after this error the subscribe not working.
I expect that it should work...
This a quickly and simple plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Apb3x30Fbggpw4FsEAwJ?p=preview
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are not catching the error thrown by `this.searchService.searchMovie(query.key)`

You should catch the error or filter the input value before sending it to the backend.

example catch:

```
this.searchField.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
        .switchMap(term => this.searchService.search(term).catch(e=>Observable.empty()))
        .subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
```

example filtering:

```
this.searchField.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .filter(term=>term && term.trim().length > 0)
        .switchMap(term => this.searchService.search(term)))
        .subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
```

Or even better, you can use both methods :)

here is your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L8U0kPHi3Mf7EaVDHure?p=preview) edited.

Comment: Ok, It works but I have a question...How can I manage the error returned from server? Because when I obtain the error I want to destroy list after autocomplete (my use case is autocomplete input). Thanks!

Comment: @Ragnarr you can put the destroy code on the `catch` method. For ex, `.catch(e=>{this.results = []; return Observable.empty()})`

Comment: I did the same thing five minutes ago and It works. Thanks man! :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need a catch:

```
  search(term: string) {
    return this.http.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=fed69657ba4cc6e1078d2a6a95f51c8c&query=" + term)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(error => '')
  }
```

Here's the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/j1ggvND1wBYipbkZVOv2?p=preview

Basically the catch allows us to safely recover from the api error whereas without the catch the app breaks.

Comment: It works but I have a question...In this way I can't use the error returned from server because you write .catch(error => ''). I updated the plunker and now not works. http://plnkr.co/edit/quDPGxkvOIgjsF9zNiBm?p=preview. Thanks.